# Интеграция piechart

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Всем привет! Пытаюсь интегрировать  [piechart](https://github.com/zemirco/swift-piechart) , но вылетает ошибка does not conform to protocol PiechartDelegate, подскажите что делаю не так, как от этого избавится?

Comment: предположу, что у вас нет всех методов, которые в протоколе объявлены как обыязательные

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что что объявлять в данном случае нужно так     ` public func setInfo(_ total: CGFloat, slice: Piechart.Slice) -> String {
        setInfo(slice: Piechart.Slice) -> String
    }

    public func setSubtitle(_ total: CGFloat, slice: Piechart.Slice) -> String {
        setSubtitle(slice: Piechart.Slice) -> String
    } `

Comment: в протоколе там две функции setInfo и setSubtitle. вам надо чтобы обе присутствовали в классе, который объявлен делегатом

Comment: Не могу понять, в самом примере эти функции не реализованы и все работает... но даже если реализовывать, я не много не понимаю что там должно быть...

Comment: видимо в примере делегат не объявлен

Comment: есть там в примере эти функции. в классе ViewController.swift строки 45-51

Comment: дааа, спасибо! я их реализовывал в didReceiveMemoryWarning, теперь все работает!

Comment: ну знаете ли...

Comment: Ну да, тупанул( но Вам спасибо!

Comment: либо тогда удаляйте вопрос, либо публикуйте свой ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно реализовать

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PiechartDelegate {


func setSubtitle(_ total: CGFloat, slice: Piechart.Slice) -> String {
    return "\(Int(slice.value / total * 100))% \(slice.text!)"
}

func setInfo(_ total: CGFloat, slice: Piechart.Slice) -> String {
    return "\(Int(slice.value))/\(Int(total))"
}
```